# HttpClient changing request URI when called from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am implementing a transparent server-side proxy for an ASP.NET MVC application which wants to communicate with an API on another server; the code is fairly straightforward:

```
public class TransparentProxyDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private static readonly Uri ApiUri;
    private static readonly HttpClient Client;

    static TransparentProxyDelegatingHandler()
    {
        var apiServer = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"]);
        ApiUri = new Uri(apiServer);
        Client = new HttpClient();
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("X-Forwarded-For", request.GetClientIpAddress());
        request.RequestUri = TranslateIncomingRequestToUpstreamApi(request);
        request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Clear();

        var response = await Client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }

    private static Uri TranslateIncomingRequestToUpstreamApi(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var forwardUri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri)
        {
            Host = ApiUri.Host,
            Path = request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Replace("/Proxy", string.Empty)
        };
        return forwardUri.Uri;
    }
}
```

So if I query `GET https://ui.myserver.com/proxy/timesheets?from=2018-01-01`, the request URI gets changed by the proxy to `GET https://api.myserver.com/timesheets?from=2018-01-01`, and I can verify this in the debugger; however, when the `SendAsync` method is invoked, the hostname part of the request URI is changed back to `https://ui.myserver.com`, and the call fails.

Why is it changing the value of `request.RequestUri` when I call `SendAsync` ? I've checked the source in GitHub (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs), but none of the conditions for changing the value seem to apply in my case. Unfortunately the GitHub source does not align with the debug symbols, so I can't seem to step into the `HttpClient` source to figure out what's really going on.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the cause of my problem; I needed to set change the Host header; the initial request to the proxy set it to the hostname of the UI (ui.myserver.com), and that overrides the hostname of the proxy that was set in the request. So if I add the following:

```
request.Headers.Host = $"{ApiUri.Host}:{ApiUri.Port}";
```

then everything magically works.